# Does mongodb create index for items that do not match fitler in partial index with unique constraint?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

The documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-partial/#partial-index-with-unique-constraint) says that it allows insertion of the item, which is what I want. But I also want to index the field but without the unique constraint if the filter doesn't match i.e, if the partial filter matches, I want the filed to be unique, if it doesn't match, I don't want it to be unique, but still needs to be indexed.

I'm getting similar query time for queries that match the filter and which doesn't. `62809ns` for that matching the filter, `65098ns` for query that doesn't match the filter.
I ran the test on collection with 10Mill docs. I ran this multiple times and doing `db.collection.getPlanCache().clear()` before each query and am getting similar result each time. So, is it safe to assume that indexes are being created for both?

Comment: You can try it and figure this out yourself?

Comment: @D.SM I'm getting similar query time for queries that match the filter and which doesn't. `62809ns` for that matching the filter, `65098ns` for query that doesn't match the filter. I ran the test on collection with 10Mill docs. I ran this multiple times and doing `db.collection.getPlanCache().clear()` before each query and am getting similar result each time. So, I'm assuming that indexes are being created here.

Comment: Add that to the question. If you are asking about query performance, add queries and query plans also.